# What is the best way to prevent REST API from bulk user registration?

Tags: rest, registration, captcha

For example I have a REST path /user/registration to be able the users to sign in, of course this path is not protected by token, because the registration is free, that's why I can not identify them. So my question is that how can we prevent the API from bulk registration by a robot? I know that I can use activation email, but it can be also processed by a robot. I can not use Captcha, because it is a REST API :(

What can I do, please help?
Any ideas?Thanks